# Tell First bone of IK Tentacle to keep rotating

Tags: rigging

I am currently trying to find a solution for the old "IK glitchy behavior" problem. I got this tentacle like rig set up, and I want to tell the root bone, the very first bone in the chain, to just keep rotating around in a circle without the strange behavior it has shown in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JO-26kScLJQ

Does anyone know what to do here? I personally think that a constraint or setting for the first bone to continue rotating could help, but I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: Take a look at Pierrick Picaut's [Advanced Rigging: Tentacles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBXFJA6UdaI) YouTube tutorial.

Comment: can u show us a link/video/example how you want it to be?

Comment: if this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndWKr.gif is a solution for you, i can write an answer

Comment: @Chris I already know the solution shown from your GIF, thank you for the suggestion, but that's not what I want. What I want is something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmcyrFZEt18 with the IK and the handle an all. The video is just a rough demonstration of the " rotating around " I meant.